# Пропадает блок при наведении на картинку (hover)

Tags: html, css, hover

Снова обращаюсь к вам, дорогие гуру. Проблема заключается в том, что при наведении на картинку "Заказать" исчезает блок с краткой информацией (заменяемый блок псевдоклассом hover). Т.е. при наведении на основную картинку происходит замена блока - первый блок исчезает и отображается второй блок с "полной информацией". Но при наведении курсора на картинку с заказом - исчезает блок с классом "do". На картинку "Заказать" планирую припаять модальное окно с формой.

```css
.comf {
  margin-top: 16%;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.pre p {
  width: 301px;
  height: 226px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 18px 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50.4%;
  left: 50.0%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.pre p:hover,
img:hover+p {
  opacity: 1;
}

.pre .col-md-4>div {
  position: relative;
}

.do {
  position: relative;
}

.posle p {
  width: 301px;
  height: 226px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Scada;
  padding: 18px 20px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 140px;
  left: 50.0%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.comf .do p {
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: Scada;
  font-size: 17px;
  bottom: 17px;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(28, 82, 95, 0.6);
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 29px 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 1px 4px;
}

.posle p:hover,
img:hover+p {
  opacity: 1;
}

.posle .col-md-4>div {
  position: relative;
}

.posle {
  display: none;
}

.comf:hover .posle {
  display: block;
}

.comf:hover .do {
  display: none;
}

.zakaz img {
  position: relative;
  right: 8px;
}

.uslbot {
  margin-top: 5%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  <div class="comf">
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/cvWSra/usl2.jpg">

    <div class="zakaz">
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/frX6jv/zakaz.png" alt="">

    </div>

    <div class="posle">
      <p>Парам пам пам</p>
    </div>
    <div class="do">
      <p>Парам пам пам</p>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Не вижу класса 'pre' в html коде

Answer (score 0):

так ты его скрываешь

```
.comf:hover .do {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Так мне и надо его скрывать при замене блоков

Answer (score 0):

```
.comf:hover .do {
    display:none;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Нафига менять z-index?